# How to set custom/editable site name and discription Django CMS

Tags: django, django-cms

How to set a custom/editable sitename and site discription in Django CMS.
The sitename and discription should be editable via Django CMS!

[Check the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3w6tu.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but if I understand you correctly, you want to

1. put a placeholder in your template and
2. add a text plugin to that via the structure view.

```html
<!-- your template, e.g. base.html -->

{% placeholder "title" %}
```

Then, in your structure view (button at the top right in your screenshot) you should see the placeholder and be able to add a text plugin with the title there.